# Split multiple words started with @ sign

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var test = "Hello all, this is a message and i want to mention @john, @smith and @jane...";
```

And what i want to get is:

```
var result = ["john", "smith", "jane"];
```

i can take the last username in the string but not all of them. I am OK with regexp or other string functions.

Thank you.

Comment: @Joren i didnt try much actually. i saw another question to get only one value from string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible using a single regex :

```
var result = test.match(/@\w+/g).join('').match(/\w+/g);
```

You might need to deal with situations in which the regex finds nothing :

```
var result = test.match(/@\w+/g);
result = result ? result.join('').match(/\w+/g) : [];
```

Comment: i still have faith that one day i will learn regexp. it looks like too complicated always to me. btw, thanks. this works too.

Comment: @AliOguzhanYildiz Here is a good starting point : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
/(^|\W)@\w+/g
```

JavaScript:

```
var test = "Hello all, this is a message and i want to mention @john, @smith and @jane";  
var names = test.match(/(^|\W)@\w+/g);
console.log(names);
```

Result:

```
0: "@john"
1: "@smith"
2: "@jane"
```

Live example on **RegExr**:
http://regexr.com?36t6g

Comment: i wanted to names without @ sign. purely. but i am ok wtih this too. i can handle rest. thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. Just replace away the @ afterwards :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = "Hello all, this is a message and i want to mention @john, @smith and @jane...";  
var patt = /(^|\s)@([^ ]*)/g;
var answer = test.match(patt)
```

Should get what you want

Like this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVHSh/)

Comment: thanks but same as above. this gives names as "@john," "@jane..."